# In JavaScript, is '!=' the same as '!=='?

Tags: javascript, syntax

> **Possible Duplicates:** 
> [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use) 
> [What is the difference between != and !== operators in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889260/javascript-operator)

Look at [this commit](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/36c99dc0c7a745a88488f519b38de811d6d4c8d9#L0R543):

Is `!=` the same as `!==` in JavaScript?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs

Comment: @S.Lott: He needed to have known that they were called "Javascript comparison operators" for one thing - which the question doesn't imply he does (to be fair to the original poster).

Comment: Try to type in `!==` in google and see what results you get. Even `javascript !==` - so google won't help

Comment: They are different: one has an extra =

Comment: Another dupe specific to `!=`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889260/javascript-operator

Comment: Who's cranky? I was meerly trying to support the OP... you can't search google or SO for operators.

Comment: @fudgey: You can search Google for a lot of things.. maybe he didnt find it.. SLott's comment is off base

Comment: You aren't supposed to up-vote duplicate questions.  Close them and point them to the previously asked question so we don't clutter the database.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

They are subtly not the same.

`!=`  checks the value
`!==` checks the value and type

```
'1' != 1   // false (these two are the same)
'1' !== 1 // true (these two are **not** the same).
```

In the previous example. The first half of the expression is a string, the second half is an integer.

Answer (score 15):

From *[JavaScript syntax, Operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Operators)*,

!==   Not identical

!=    Not equal

AND "Identical means equal and of same type."

From *[5.4. Equality Operators](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch05_04.htm)*:

"In JavaScript, numbers, strings, and boolean values are compared by value.
...
On the other hand, objects, arrays, and functions are compared by reference. "

--

So in summary, are they the same?  No, because there is an additional test with !== (over !=) for type *sameness* as well as *equalness*.

Answer (score 10):

No, it is not the same. See for example [here](http://www.devguru.com/Technologies/ecmascript/quickref/comparison_operators.html).

```
4 !== '4' returns true   (and 4 === '4' returns false)
4 != '4'  returns false  (and 4 == '4'  returns true)
```

Comment: And for the full skinny, there's nothing like the spec. You can download the latest from here: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/drafts/  It's the PDF file starting with "tc39-" (as of this writing, tc39-2009-050.pdf). That says it's a draft, but it was voted through earlier this month.

Comment: And see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use/1813267#1813267 how to read the spec!

Comment: Hehe, the fact that you need a manual to read a spec really says something about the quality of the spec itself :)

Answer (score 8):

The big difference is that != performs type coercion. That is, one value is effectively cast to the other before equality is checked. This is why, as in [Amadiere's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946063/in-javascript-is-the-same-as/1946081#1946081):

```
'1' != 1
```

evaluates to false. The same holds true for == v. ===. In general, avoid == and != unless you specifically want coercion to be performed. Use === and !== and check for exactly the result you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

It checks not only value, but also the type of the things compared.

This is also the same in [PHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) and some other languages too.