# Invert a condition in Perl

Tags: perl, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to match on fieldA and everything in fieldB as long as it isn't 456:

```
if ($fieldA==123 && $fieldB!==456)
```

What is the syntax I should use for fieldB?   Is it !== or !=? I've also seen something like `!$fieldB==456`. It's really the syntax of fieldB that I'm having issues with.

Comment: Read the [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) manual page and search for `!=`.

Comment: Could you please be clearer for which conditions you'd like the `if` to be entered?

Comment: Perhaps the real question is where `!==` came from? [From JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889260/what-is-the-difference-between-and-operators-in-javascript)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you want to use

```
if ($fieldA == 123 && $fieldB != 456)
```

If you wanted to negate both you could use the form

```
unless ($fieldA == 123 && $fieldB == 456)
```

Which would evaluate to true if both assertions were false.

Comment: Skarface:  Does your !=456 take into account that I'm trying to compare 456 vs. equal 456?    I thought that != means NOT EQUAL just like == means comparison. What I need is NOT COMPARED TO 456.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  if (a != 5) will evaluate to true if a is not set to 5.  just like if (a == 5) will eavluate to true if a is set to 5.

Comment: @Alby: What do you mean by "not compared to"?

Comment: Thanks skarface. Using != worked.  I was assuming that if I needed "==" to compare that I needed a similar !== if I wanted  the inverse.

Comment: Reading `man perlop` would be preferable too just guessing operators.