# Remove 3 columns from all sheets except Main Menu on Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-editor

I have no background in programming but I am trying to come up with a Script on Google Sheets to remove the first 3 columns in my Workbook except the "Main Menu". I have 61 tabs so I didn't want to individually remove them. So, the following is what I managed to come up with from doing the googling. I kept seeing the error "Cannot find method deleteColumns()." Any help would be much appreciated.

```
function QuickDelete() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sss = ss.getSheets();

  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
     switch(sss[i].getSheetName()) {
     case "Main Menu":
         break;
     default:
        ss.deleteColumns(sss[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In your `for` loop, your are using `sheets`, which you haven't defined before. You have to change `sss` to `sheets` or viceversa everywhere in your code.
- You have to provide two parameters to [deleteColumns](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleteColumns(Integer,Integer)), the position of the `first column` to delete and the `number of columns` to delete. In your case, `1` and `3` respectively.

So your code could be like this:

```
function QuickDelete() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if (sheets[i].getSheetName() !== "Main Menu") {
      sheets[i].deleteColumns(1, 3)
    }
  }
}
```

Also, the `switch` statement makes sense if there are many `values` you have to check your `expression` with. In your case, I'd better use `if` to check if the name of the sheet is `Main Menu`.

- Reference:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleteColumns(Integer,Integer)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Comment: I tried your method as well as ADW's and both method works! Also, I was wondering what does the !== notation mean?

Comment: @FatinNabilah check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889260/javascript-operator). Also, please consider accepting one of the answers that provided the solution to your problem by [clicking the "check mark" button underneath the vote buttons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), as this community relies on this to share knowledge to other users.

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems that need to be fixed.

1. You are looping over `sheets`. But you should be looping over `sss`.
2. The `deleteColumns()` [method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleteColumns(Integer,Integer)) needs to be applied to the sheet i.e. `sss[i]`

Something like `sss[i].deleteColumns(columnPosition, howMany)`.

```
function QuickDelete() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sss = ss.getSheets();
  var columnPosition = 1; // Delete from the 1st column
  var howMany = 3; // Delete 3 columns

  for (i = 0; i < sss.length; i++) {
    switch(sss[i].getSheetName()) {
      case "Main Menu":
        break;
      default:
        sss[i].deleteColumns(columnPosition, howMany)
    }
  } 
}
```

All the best.