# Javascript / assign value with || and ! ==

Tags: javascript

I know this is a very basic question but I could not find a source to explain this code snippet. 
What is this code mean?

```js
hasChanged = hasChanged || nextStateForKey !== previousStateForKey
```

I know the meaning of !== but 
How does `!==` work here?

Comment: `!==` works the same way - it returns a boolean. It will be `true` if `nextStateForKey` is not equal to `previousStateForKey` and `false` otherwise

Comment: It assigns the value of `hasChanged` *or* `nextStateForKey !== previousStateForKey` to `hasChanged`, depending on which is falsey.

Comment: [What does the construct x = x || y mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2802055) + [Javascript operator !==](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1889260)